Mean, Variance and Correlation Function of a quadratic SDE
I am struggling with the following nonlinear SDE:
$ ds=dt(-\Omega s^2(t)+\alpha s(t)+\beta)  + d\xi(t)(\gamma (1-s(t))) $
$ d\xi = dt(-\frac{1}{\tau} \xi(t)) + \sigma dW(t) $
Where $\alpha$, $\Omega$, $\beta$, $\tau$, $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ are constants and $W$ is a Wiener process. I don't need the full solution, I just need the mean, variance and correlation function of $s$.
Also related, is there a systematic way to linearize these kinds of nonlinear stochastic differential equations? I am also content with the linearized form.
